# Parsing inconsistent XML file in Python to upload it to DB with Django

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse an XML file containing multiple elements of the following structure:

```
<root attribute_xmlns=date_as_str>
    <element1 attrib1="str" attrib2="str" attrib3="str" attrib4="str">
        <element2>
            <element21>Some text</element21>
            <element22>Some other text</element22>
        </element2>
        <element3>
            <element31 attrib1="str" attrib2="str" attrib3="str"/>
            <element32 attrib1="str" attrib3="str"/>
            <element33 attrib1="str" attrib2="str" attrib3="str" attrib4="str"/>
        </element3>
    </element1>
</root>
```

Some information I want to retrieve is held within attributes' texts of elements and some in the element text.

I was trying to save it in CSV with `xml.etree.ElementTree` by iterating over each level of the file and getting consecutive attributes' and elements text. The problem however is that the file is internally inconsistent. There may be missing attributes in some of the elements or elements have no value. In such cases - my final CSV file is just a big mess.

How can I get that done? My plan is to upload this data into SQL DB in Django app.

Comment: The proper way to handle invalid XML is to reject it. If you still want to use, you must be aware that you are in uncharted territory and all guarantees are off. You can try to use a different library which may be more forgiving, like `beautifulsoup`, or you can implement your own parser.

Comment: Well it's hard to disagree with you and if I didn't have to handle it - I wouldn't. BeautifulSoup parsing of xml data seems promising, however. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what kind of business you are into, but simeone must have created that file and it may be an option to ask them to fix the errors ;)